# Saving a highscore

Tags: ios, swift

I've seen quite a few threads on here asking this and I've followed a few and can't seem to get this to save AFTER the app is killed and reopened. As far as working from game to game (without killing the app) it saves appropriately.

Here are the instances of my highscore variable. I left out some of the styling and where I display the high score. I have a feeling it's something with the declaration?

```
//delarations
var highScore = Int()
var highScoreLabel = UILabel()

//post game
if score > highScore {
   saveHighScore()
   scoreIsHigher = true
   }

//and the function
func saveHighScore() {
    let highScoreData = UserDefaults.standard
    highScore = score
    highScoreData.setValue(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
}
```

Edit:
I was missing this portion of code in the pregame state, which seems to be what triggers the data being loaded in.

```
let highScoreData = UserDefaults.standard
if (highScoreData.object(forKey: "highScore") != nil) {
        highScore = highScoreData.value(forKey: "highScore") as! NSInteger!
    }
```

Comment: What is the question here? Could you be more specific about what exactly you want as an answer?

Comment: Where do you load the high score?

Comment: When do you call `saveHighScore`? And why do you incorrectly use `saveValue(forKey:)` instead of `save(forKey:)`? Do not needlessly use KVC.

Comment: The question is how do I make the high score save even after the app is force closed at some point or another. I call saveHighScore in the post game after a score is calculated, as seen above. That's the only time.

Comment: Where is `score` coming from in the `saveHighScore()` function? I don't see any parameter or other declaration named `score`.

Comment: Score is a global variable initially set to 0, and post game is calculated based on how many matches were made, etc. The score and high score are displaying post-game on my menu perfectly. The high score changes immediately as it should if the score is higher than the previous high score. If I go into the app switcher and kill the app and open it back up the high score is back to 0

Comment: Where do you load it when the app starts?  Show that code

Comment: Assuming you want the score to persist even when you kill the app via the app switcher, the only solution is to persist the score every time it changes.

Comment: I wasn't loading the code in I don't believe. I added an edit to my original question with the updated code. It seems to work fine now. Thanks for mentioning that everyone -- I overlooked that.

Comment: Again, don't use `object(forKey:)`, use `integer(forKey:)`

Comment: @rmaddy it is not `save(forKey:)` the correct way to set a value in Swift 3 is `set(_ value: Any?, forKey: String)` in his case `highScoreData.set(highScore, forKey: "highScore")`

Comment: @LeoDabus Oops. Yes, I meant `set(_:,forKey:)`, not `save(forKey:)`. Either way, no one should use `setValue(forKey:)` with `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set(_:forKey:)`, not set `setValue(_:forKey:)`

`setValue(_:forKey:)` is a KVO method, and is not the way to save to UserDefaults.

You need to update the high score to `UserDefaults` as soon as the user earns a new high score, and read it from UserDefaults when you launch.

Answer (score 0):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
```

Using .set(_, forKey: ) methods should solve your problem.